# If condition checking if a member has purchased a product

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements

Hi I want to check if the member has purchased the product or not. If the member has purchased to display something different.

Sample date below:

```
products
productID, title, runTime, imageLarge, classification
1, noah, 128 minutes, noahLarge.jpg, M
2, left behind, 105 minutes, leftBehindLarge.jpg, MA 15+
3, green lantern, 133 minutes, greenLantern.jpg, M

invoice
invoiceID, memberID, purchaseDate
1,11,1/10/2014
2,13,15/10/2014


productsinvoice
invoiceID, productID
1, 2
1, 3
2, 1
2, 2

members
memberID, username, pass, first name, last name
11, bob, fwofefef, bob, marley
13, prius, f334ff43f, eski, martey
```

So when a user has purchased a product it displays it a little different and it only displays it differently if they have purchased THAT product.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
  {
  echo '
  <h4>$'. $row['price'] .'</h4>
  <p><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(' .$row['productID'] . ')" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add to cart"/></p>';
  }
  else {
  echo '
  <a href="../pages/movieWatch.php?productID='.$row['productID'].'" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"> Stream</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd"> Download</a>';
  }
```

In MySQL query I have already joined invoice and productsinvoice I just have no idea at all what to write for this if condition.

```
(if condition logic)
If (the user has purchased this product)
{

}
else (if the user has not purchased this product)
{

}
```

Comment: Do you have a loop of a product then display if a member purchase that product?

Comment: I have them all in a loop and inside that loop and I have an if condition. http://latestcinema.3eeweb.com/ theres a link to the site so when a member purchases a product it displays differently to the product that was purchased. I have no idea what to write for the if conidition tho

Comment: Basically when a product is purchased instead of it listen the price and add to cart button has different buttons.

Comment: What do you mean different?
if a member purchase the product? what would happen?
if not, what would happen?

Comment: If no items have been purchased i want it to have the product price and the add to cart button and if that specific product has been purchased i want it to say stream/download instead of listing the price and having the add to cart button.

Comment: Ok, I got your point, but why this is your condition?
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))  ???
and where is your JOIN statement for your tables?

Comment: I think your invoice table should include the product_id

Comment: If i put the productID in the invoice table wont that make it impossible to purchase multiple items in the 1 transaction?

Comment: Yep, just like your productinvoice table. . if 2 product then insert 2 rows in invoice table.

Comment: then you can use this query.
select
 i.invoiceID,i.memberID,i.purchaseDate,p.productID
from
 invoice i left join product p
 on i.productID = p.productID

Comment: What would the logic be for the If condition? ill try merging the tables and trying your query

Comment: Your first query. . "select * from products" then loop the result, inside the loop is your join statement - 
select
 i.invoiceID,i.memberID,i.purchaseDate,p.productID
from
 invoice i left join product p
 on i.productID = p.productID
where
 p.productID = $productID  and i.memberID = $memberID

----------------------------------
if there is a result in second query it means the member purchase that product.